# Java SSL error : "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

Tags: java, ssl, https, box-api

I'm facing strange issue:

1. I have a code working with Box API (for different customers and different box accounts), this code works fine for all customers of ours , expect one customer and works fine almost to all his box accounts (dosens) except 3 his accounts. I'm getting on them "unable to find valid certification path to requested target" - SSL error.
2. When I'm executing our code on those problematics accounts as stand alone process everything is working fine.
3. When work with those accounts (even with one of them) executed as part of multi-threaded process (no SSL Socket sharing between threads, no shared resources between threads, each thread can do different jobs, and may not work with Box at all (and even other accounts of the same customer or other customers works fine in the same multi-threaded process), but with other HTTPS servers like Sharepoint or Google) then I'm getting this strange error from Box API that saying :
   *"PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"*

So, this issue is makes me crazy. Standalone execution works fine (on the same machine where multi-threaded execution throws that error, again SSL Socket is not shared between threads).
So, my question is what can confuse SSL Socket in JAVA in that way that if fails for validate certificate (while cacerts is valid, as standalone execution working just fine, and even other accounts of the same customer or other customers works fine in the same multi-threaded process).

**Update** :
Seems that during file downloading we got redirected to zones-traffic-manager00025.eu-west-2.aws.prod.box.net.
While accessing this in the browser, the host name seems not much CN in the certificate, which is wildcard for *.box.com. But anyway browser says it's an invalid name. In the exception in Java of SunCertPathBuilderException we see in the AdjacencyList next chain of certificate verification which is somehow broken :

1. cn in certificate : **zones-traffic-manager00025.eu-west-2.aws.prod.box.net** Issued by : **cn=production web services authority**
2. **cn=production web services authority** issued by **cn=production intermediate authority**
3. **cn=production intermediate authority** issued by **cn=production root authority**
   And cn=production root authority is not verified.

Please advise
Thanks

Thanks !!!

Comment: ITYM cert doesn't 'match' CN. SSL/TLS certificates have been using **SAN (Subject Alternative Name) NOT CN (CommonName)** for over a decade now, and the cert both I and ssllabs get from 107.52.27.193 has SAN=`*.box.net,www.box.net` which is indeed wrong for that name because wildcards can only be one-level; there are dozens of Qs about this. But it is signed by GeoTrust RSA CA 2018 under Digicert Global Root CA, which is a valid CA path, not the names you report; are you sure your connection isn't going through a proxy or interceptor like AV, IDS/IPS/DLP, etc? ...

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks,  connection is goes directly to box, no proxy or anything else (IDS or so), servers running in AWS (direct connection no NAT Gateway). Other HTTPS connections working fine on that server, (to AWS S3 working fine and they also signed by GeoTrust RSA CA). I see also another BOX traffic manager server is the same process and also fails, almost same name zones-traffic-manager00031.eu-west-2.aws.prod.box.net.  Thanks

Comment: And those names that I wrote above I took from the process heap dump in the SSL exception, in the AdjacencyList. So I guess this is chain that Java is trying to build to verify certificate

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 After reading you comment I digged a bit in the sniffed network data and I see TLS 1.2 initiation with box server nlb-box-c7-0-2caff61596e8a29b.elb.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com wich reposne with 3 certificates 1) id-at-commonName=zones-traffic-manager00045.eu-west-2.aws.prod issued by id-at-commonName=Production Web Services Authority 2) id-at-commonName=Production Web Services Authority issued by id-at-commonName=Production Intermediate Authority 3) id-at-commonName=Production Intermediate Authority issued by id-at-commonName=Production Root Authority

Comment: That second 'zones-traffic' name maps to the same machine and gets the same certs, but the nlb-box name is a different machine and for THAT machine I do get a cert chain with those CA names, which are indeed not publicly known. It does claim a CRLDP within box.net, but that doesn't connect for me so I can't test it. I have no idea why your app is trying to connect to these servers, and why they are badly configured (in different ways) even though they appear to be actual box servers (at least mapped by box's DNS zone). Good luck.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks, actually those servers deliver file download from box, and it's done by BOX SDK internally, it's not that our app going to there explicitly.